# Apparently stripped holes in dryer door hinges

Tags: screws, dryer

I removed  the door of an OLD Maytag dryer(DG408) to repair the latching mechanism. I followed Youtube repair video (*that was linked to the repair part on order site*) step by step, worked like a charm.

However, when I went to go reinstall door, ALL FOUR of the hinge screws just spin in the holes. I can take screws with my hand and push in and out - nothing grabs whatsoever. They were the only screws removed so I know I didn't mix them up.

Initially removed screws easily with a manual screwdriver, supporting door to be sure I didn't bend anything. Holes and screws are tiny, can detect nothing behind them or see any threads, though holes are so tiny I'm not sure. (*Photos below*)

I am wondering if the previously posted solution,  by "Fred" I think,  to a similar question asked by "Tiffany  in 2019 would work? Here's what it said:

> take the good screws to a local hardware store and ask for a matching
> tap to clean or re-tap the threads in the door. The hardware store
> person should find a nut to fit the screw, identifying the thread as
> metric or SAE and then match the tap tool accordingly.
>
> For a one-off task such as this, you can get away without a tap
> handle. Use an adjustable wrench set to match the flats on the tap,
> place the tap in the hole and attempt to start the cutting threads to
> match the probably-damaged threads in the dryer wall. Because the
> threads were there previously, you won't have to use the forward
> half-turn, backwards quarter-turn practice used for tapping a drilled
> hole. A bit of lubricant would be useful, a light oil or even motor
> oil.

Any help GREATLY appreciated.

[image]

([image]

[image]

Comment: Those don't look like threaded holes to me.  Are you sure there were not nut or some other type of bracket with threaded holes behind that panel that fell down once you removed the screws?

Comment: The metal seems real thin to create a good tapped thread. I would probably just use a slightly thicker screw, or look at ways of pluggreing the hole a little, like with stainless steel wire half in half out so screw push

es wire again side of hole all around.

Comment: @jwh thought the same, perhaps a pic of the screws would help. If they are really bolts, then we know the real fix.

Comment: I doubt self threading screws would be used to hold a door on.  Open up the dryer and look for the nuts/clips/brackets that have fallen inside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hinge screws do not engage threads in the sheet metal of the front panel, they are bolts designed to be held in place by nuts, which fell down inside your dryer when you removed the door.

Well, not nuts exactly. The retaining parts are actually small metal plates, one per hinge, with two threaded holes each, that align with the holes in the front panel.

You will have to remove the front panel to install the door. Fortunately this is very easy: remove the two screws near the bottom of the panel, pull the bottom of the panel out, and slide the panel down to disengage it at the top. Disconnect the door switch wires and remove them from the front panel.

Find the retaining plates that have fallen down inside the dryer. It should be obvious how to use these to attach the door to the front panel. A dab of construction adhesive or contact cement might help hold the plates in place during assembly.

Don't forget to re-connect the door switch wires. Close the door before installing the front panel; this job does not require any comic relief.

Comment: THANK YOU! I took the dryer front panel partially off previously, thinking maybe there were bolts or something behind which fell off and didn't see anything. Just did it again and found the tiny, dark metal plates under (a fair amount of) dust in the bottom groove of front panel. Didn't have adhesive or cement but with a few contortions and even more cursing, it's working again. THANKS AGAIN, life saver!!!